# Class.forName() versus direct class loading

Tags: java, class

I found some code loading resources this way:

```
Class.forName(myClass.class.getName()).getResourceAsStream("myResource");
```

First, I wondered about the interest of using such a structure. It appears `Class.forName("className")` enables a dynamic loading, loading the class only when needed (this is the typical structure when loading a JDBC driver, for instance).

Yet, is not the dynamic loading inefficient in this case since the class is in code? Would there be any difference if I wrote the following?

```
myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myResource");
```

Comment: In this case, the dynamic class loading is definitely a waste.

Comment: Yes. The second one has a better performance... `myClass.class` *is* the `Class` object that we're looking for. No need to look up the name from that instance and to ask `Class` to find it again by that name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mmyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myResource");` should be prefered option since it does not make search. Result is the same since `myClass.class.getName()` is used in `forName`, not just predefined string.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as written.  `Class.forName` and `Class.getResourceAsStream` are doing different things.  They are interchangeable.

The only way to compare them would be if you were comparing loading a class full of (say) `static` fields initialized with data versus reading a resource containing the same data.  If that is what you are talking better, the `getResourceAsStream` approach is better in a number of respects:

- there are no limits on the amount of data you can read that way,
- you don't have to embed the data in "code",
- your memory footprint will be smaller,
- you can load just the subset of the data that you require,
- it is probably faster,
- and so on.

---

If you are asking if you can use `getResourceAsStream()` to load classes (in the normal sense), the answer is no.  Sure you can get the bytecodes, but you have to do "other stuff" to turn those bytecodes into executable classes / methods in the JVM.

Comment: If you read the question again, you will see that I know how to use the `getResourceAsStream`. I am however dubious as to how the class is loaded before calling this method: I am unsure the construction `Class.forName(myClass.class.getName())` has any sense or interest, and previous comments and answer seem to match my feeling.